# specific question on java threading + synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I know this question sounds crazy, but consider the following java snippets:

Part - I:

```
 class Consumer implements Runnable{
      private boolean shouldTerminate = false
      public void run() {
          while( !shouldTerminate ){
               //consume and perform some operation.
          }
      }

      public void terminate(){
        this.shouldTerminate = true;
      }
    }
```

So, the first question is, should I ever need to synchronize on shouldTerminate boolean? If so why? I don't mind missing the flag set to true for one or two cycles(cycle = 1 loop execution). And second, can a boolean variable ever be in a inconsistent state?(anything other than true or false)

Part - II of the question:

```
class Cache<K,V> {

  private Map<K, V> cache = new HashMap<K, V>();

  public V getValue(K key) {
     if ( !cache.containsKey(key) ) {
       synchronized(this.cache){
          V value = loadValue(key)
          cache.put(key, value);
       }  
      } 
     return cache.get(key);
  }
}
```

Should access to the whole map be synchronized? Is there any possibility where two threads try to run this method, with one "writer thread" halfway through the process of storing value into the map and simultaneously, a "reader thread" invoking the "contains" method. Will this cause the JVM to blow up? (I don't mind overwriting values in the map -- if two writer threads try to load at the same time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of the code examples have broken concurrency.

The first one requires at least the field marked `volatile` or else the other thread might never see the variable being changed (it may store its value in CPU cache or a register, and not check whether the value in memory has changed).

The second one is even more broken, because the internals of `HashMap` are no thread-safe and it's not just a single value but a complex data structure - using it from many threads produces completely unpredictable results. The general rule is that both reading and writing the shared state must be synchronized. You may also use `ConcurrentHashMap` for better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you either synchronize on the variable, or mark the variable as volatile, there is no guarantee that separate threads' view of the object ever get reconciled. To quote the [Wikipedia artible on the Java Memory Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model)

> The major caveat of this is that as-if-serial semantics do not prevent different threads from having different views of the data.

Realistically, so long as the two threads synchronize on *some* lock at *some* time, the update to the variable will be seen.

I am wondering why you wouldn't want to mark the variable `volatile`?

Comment: well, marking a variable volatile in effect would achieve the same thing as synchronizing on the object and reading "shouldTerminate" flag. I was trying to cut corners..

Comment: No, synchronization has much broader implications than volatile. To quote: 'A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that same volatile'

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the JVM will "blow up" as such. But both cases are incorrectly synchronised, and so the results will be unpredictable. The bottom line is that JVMs are designed to behave in a particular way *if* you synchronise in a particular way; if you don't synchronise correctly, you lose that guarantee.

It's not uncommon for people to think they've found a reason why certain synchronisation can be omitted, or to unknowingly omit necessary synchronisation but with no immediately obvious problem. But with inadequate synchronisation, there is a danger that your program could *appear* to work fine in one environment, only for an issue to appear later when a particular factor is changed (e.g. moving to a machine with more CPUs, or an update to the JVM that adds a particular optimisation).

Comment: very pragmatic answer. You were right on target. I was desperately trying to avoid synchronization to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Synchronizing `shouldTerminate`: See
   Dilum's answer
2. Your bool value will
   never be inconsistent state.
3. If one
   thread is calling
   `cache.containsKey(key)` while
   another thread is calling
   `cache.put(key, value)` <s>the JVM will
   blow up (by throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`)</s>
   something bad might happen if that `put` call caused the map
   the grow, but will usually mostly work (worse than failure).

Comment: 3. Will the JVM blow up? ConcurrentModificationException only happens with a fail-fast iterator. If the map isn't synchronized itself you probably won't get an exception -- best case inconsistent data, worst an infinite loop. On the other hand, if you use Collections.synchronizedMap(), you'll just get two loadValues/puts. That's ok depending on the requirements.

Comment: I tend to agree with the last comment -- by the JVM "blowing up" I think the asker probably had in mind something worse than a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @Peter: You're right. I was a bit hasty posting that one. The `ConcurrentModificationException` is only thrown by the default collection view iterator for HashMap.

Comment: Yes, What I meant by JVM blowing up == JVM crashing due to memory corruption etc.. (which can easily happen with C/C++ programs)

Comment: no worries, and I definitely agree with "worse than failure" :-)